# Determining portal camera world matrix in three.js

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js

I'm working on a small WebVR web metaverse project, where THREE.js scenes are connected using portals (like you would find in the Valve game).

I have found a great OpenGL.ES tutorial, which helped me get the rendering down. What I couldn't figure out is how to translate the C/C++ code for determining the relative camera matrix to js/three.js.

Here is said [OpenGL snippet](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Mini-Portal#Building_a_new_camera). The image next to it is pretty great *(I can't embed more than two links)*.`C'` is what I am trying to determine, given `C, P1, P2`.

---

Here are 3 of my attempts, `toPortal` and `this` are meshes (this being the portal in the same scene as the camera, toPortal being the other portal (exit)).

```
//Attempt 1
//Commented out Y rotation, as without it is already very wrong.
Portal.prototype.getPortalViewMatrix1 = function (camera) {
    var inverse_view_to_source = new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse(camera.matrixWorld).multiply(this.matrix);
    var new_mat = this.toPortal.matrix.clone().multiply(inverse_view_to_source);
    var rot = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(Math.PI);

    // new_mat.rotateY(3.14);
    //return new_mat;
    return rot.multiply(new_mat);
};

//Attempt 2
//Commented out Y rotation, as without it is already very wrong.
Portal.prototype.getPortalViewMatrix2 = function (originalView) {
    var mv = originalView.multiply(this.matrix);
    var portalCam = mv.multiply(new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse(this.toPortal.matrix));

    return portalCam;
};

//Wrong, but the most right attempt, syncs up the two different scenes,
//but doesn't take into account goal portal position, rotation
//Only works with portals on (0,0,0), unrotated.
Portal.prototype.getPortalViewMatrix = function (originalView) {
    return this.toPortal.matrix.clone().multiply(originalView);
};
```

These are my current debug scenes, with arrows indicating the portal entrances
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43693599/scenes.png

Here are JSFiddle and JSBin links

**I will add it to the comments, I can't add it here**

*Note that you will have to view the result in a different window in order for fullscreen and pointerlock api to work.* *In JSbin you can easily do this by pressing the arrow in the top right of the result screen.*

**EDIT**
I have been trying other things, and I seemed to be able to get the translation matrix (position only) right. Of course now I can't rotate portals (they must be facing exactly opposite of eachother).

```
        getPortalViewMatrix3(originalView: THREE.Matrix4) {
        var t = new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(this.position.x - this.toPortal.position.x, this.position.y - this.toPortal.position.y, this.position.z - this.toPortal.position.z);
        t.getInverse(t);
        return t.multiply(originalView);
    }
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Rahazan/wrt54rjs/, http://jsbin.com/sowazakogi/2/edit?html,output

Comment: any updates here? i may need portals after a while too, could try to help if you're stuck still.

Comment: Still using the same code fom the edit (I added a week back). So it only works with portals that are aligned rotation-wise. Any help is welcome! :)

Comment: Thanks for your post. This interests me as well. I'm creating a Google Cardboard app with a narrated tour of the solar system for my non-profit (still finalizing subject matter, but this is a good start). The best way to travel between planets instantly is to open up a wormhole of course. I don't have a solution currently, but if I figure something out I will share the code here for sure. +1 for this question.